# plot matrix with epslatex

Tags: matrices, plot, gnuplot

When plotting a data matrix with the plot command and epslatex terminal the generated image is correct. However, the generated latex file outputs also the source path, i.e. 'Date/data_file.txt'.

Any ideas why this is so?

```
set terminal epslatex color size 4in,1.5in

set xrange[ 0:1000 ]
set yrange[ 200:0 ]

set output 'my_file.tex'
plot 'Data/data_file.txt' using 1:2:3 matrix w image
```

Comment: I found the solution: just append title command to the last line and every thing works! plot 'Data/data_file.txt' using 1:2:3 matrix w image title ''

Comment: You can also use `notitle` instead of an empty title or unset the key to completely remove the legend.